# User control not retaining property values

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, properties

I have a very simple user control with 5 radio buttons on it, and 3 properties (ID, RatingSetID, and Rating). On the initial load of the page they are on, the code acquires data and places the data into the 3 properties. However, when the submit button is clicked the page reloads and the 3 properties get reset to 0, they are in the !IsPostBack as well. I know I am missing something simple.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What code would you like to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usercontrol might be reloaded when postback if you load this control on the fly

Comment: The control is placed on the form at design time. I am however, adding attributes in the Page_Init, could htis be the issue?

Comment: your controls properties don't get into ViewState I suppose. Could you post your code where you define the usercontrols properties?

Comment: Please take a look also at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538600/usercontrol-losing-viewstate-across-postback

Comment: Thank Arief, the link you gave me allowed me to correct this issue by issue ViewState to the control

Answer (score 0):

The user control get reload when the postback happens.
You can place it into an UpdatePanel it could solve your problem.

Comment: Even though the control gets reloaded, shouldnt the properties stay? How do I simply retain the property values, I dont want to use an UpdatePanel